Getting Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: [/all-pages], but I already put the export default at the bottom file
I try to make the exact structure from my past project, but when I fill in the layout.tsx (not the root) that's called ViewsLayout, i got an error:
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
Then, I omit the ViewsLayout then the error persist in:
Error: The default export is not a React Component in page: [/basically all pages]
What I'm trying to do is, export the main form from _components folder inside the example-a folder as the route, the import it to page.tsx with this structure:
example-a

This is the inside for form.tsx.

Note that the ExampleInput names are customized as it not the actual name.
I already tried the simplest way like I only put <p> Hello </p> inside the ExampleForm but the error still the same and also i already tried to move all the form content by directly insert it into the page.tsx but still got the same error.

Try using normal function instead of arrow function.

I sometimes encounter errors, but I've found a workaround. When I save both the file where the component is exporting and the file where it's importing, then kill the running React server and start it again, it works for me. I'm not sure if it will work for you, but it's worth a try.

I just solved this by changing the components that I customized using TextField from Material UI to FormControlAPI which breakdown the structure for the TextField. Thanks for your help guys
